# managed-property definied in faces-config.xml resolves as null

Tags: jsf, faces-config

I am developing a JSF app with Spring. Here is my `faces-config.xml` file.

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>loginBean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.abc.LoginBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
    <property-name>userHelper</property-name>
    <property-class>com.abc.MyHelper</property-class>
    <value>#{userHelper}</value>
  </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

In the `LoginBean` I've a setter and getter method for the property `userHelper`. But whenever I am trying to access the property `userHelper` in my `LoginBean`, I am getting `null`. What is the cause and how can I solve it?

the below is the stacktrace

```
17:43:54,325 WARNING [lifecycle] #{loginBean.login}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{loginBean.login}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.abc.LoginBean.login(LoginBean.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:170)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code from `LoginBean`. Also, I take it that `userHelper` is correctly defined as a bean and it is not as `userHelperBean` or something related, am I right?

Comment: yes , both the classes are bean only. in LoginBean i just have getter and setter methods of username&password

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the `#{userHelper}` itself is absolutely not `null`, then that can only happen if you were trying to access it already in the **constructor** of `LoginBean`. For JSF (and all other dependency injection mechanisms), it's not possible to invoke a setter with the managed property value *before* the constructor is called. So the property would *always* be `null` in the constructor.

Earliest access point would be a `@PostConstruct` method.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() { 
    System.out.println(userHelper); // Look, it should not be null.
}
```

Do the desired job in there instead of in the constructor.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, a getter is not required for a managed property. I recommend to remove it to prevent accidental usage of this getter in the view.

Comment: still no luck , this init() method itself the value is null

Comment: Well, then that can only mean that `#{userHelper}` itself is `null`. How exactly is it been registered? Does the EL expression `#{userHelper}` by itself evaluate fine in the view?

Comment: '<bean id="userHelper" class="com.abc.MyHelper">
  <property name="daoImpl" ref="daoImpl"/>
 </bean>' , this is how I registered the bean